# IPhone Accelerometer Determine Motion

Tags: iphone, accelerometer

Using the accelerometer output, how do I determine if the user (iphone mounted on waist) is walking?

Looking for a good algorithm to determine if the user is walking to determine activity transitions- standing-to-walking or walking-to-standing.

please help.

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 3):

For a previous project, I tried calculating the magnitude of the acceleration vector, and just setting a threshold of about 2g, and that worked pretty well in testing. A typical (hardware) pedometer will ignore single jolts that happen more than about a second apart, which seems like a good way to filter out occasional movement that isn't "walking".

Additionally, you could automatically adjust the threshold by examining the data for a while.

Comment: How can I examine the data? Is there an app that does that?

Comment: My thought was, write an app that just sets the accelerometer to fast updates, and logs every event that comes in. Later, you can examine that data on the desktop, in your software of choice, and try out different techniques to determine what's walking vs not.