# Detecting steps taken during walk using IPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c

is it possible that i can detect with application for the amount of indoor walk using Iphone SDK.
?
if so then what steps should i follow to achieve.

thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [logic to count steps while walking using accelerometer feature in iphone](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2047041/logic-to-count-steps-while-walking-using-accelerometer-feature-in-iphone)

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/651630/iphone-accelerometer-determine-motion and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1984003/how-to-implement-pedometer-in-iphone

Answer (score 6):

Run [AccelerometerGraph](https://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/samplecode/AccelerometerGraph/index.html) sample code and walk with the device. That will give you a rough idea of what the time between strides is, and what a stride's acceleration looks like. Then write accelerometer logging code of your own that can calculate the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, using the data from the accelerometer(s) in the device makes this possible. I wouldn't underestimate the effort to write a signal filter for this though, as it can be pretty complex if you are striving for accuracy.

There exists lots of research in this field, see [this](http://www.analog.com/library/analogDialogue/archives/41-03/pedometer.html) paper for some basics.

Comment: Agreed. I wanted to add the need for some PID in my answer too, but felt it was out of the scope of the question.  Something rudimentary could be compiled without it.  Bear in mind that a simple pedometer can be purchased for <$10 - so I'm assuming this is simply a scholarly exercise.

Answer (score 0):

Utilizing the accelerometer and a little bit of experimentation, you should be able to ascertain the number of accelerate/decelerate motions of a walker.  Then, determine the average stride length and compute the distance traveled.